# How to deal with a Toggle NSButton?

Tags: cocoa, togglebutton, nsbutton

My application contains a PLAY/PAUSE button that is set to type *Toggle* in Interface Builder. I use it - as the name reveals - to play back my assets or to pause them.
Further, I am listening to the SPACE key to enable the same functionality via the keyboard shortcut. Therefore, I use `keyDown:` from `NSResponder`in my application. This is done in another subview. The button itself is not visible at this time.
I store the current state of playback in a Singleton.

How would you update the title/alternative title for the toogle button while taking into account that its state could have been altered by the keyboard shortcut? Can I use bindings?

Comment: How, specifically, are you “listening to the space key”?

Comment: @Peter Hosey I added some infos. Thanks for the grammar edit.

Comment: Where are you implementing `keyDown:`? NSButton lets you set a keyboard shortcut on it right in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to implement the continuous update of the button title as follows. I added a programmatic binding for the state (in the example `buttonTitle`). Notice, that the `IBAction` `toggleButtonTitle:` does not directly change the button title! Instead the `updateButtonTitle` method is responsible for this task. Since `self.setButtonTitle` is called the aforementioned binding gets updated immediately.
The following example shows what I tried to describe.

```
//  BindThisAppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface BindThisAppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow* m_window;
    NSButton* m_button;
    NSString* m_buttonTitle;
    NSUInteger m_hitCount;
}

@property (readwrite, assign) IBOutlet NSWindow* window;
@property (readwrite, assign) IBOutlet NSButton* button;
@property (readwrite, assign) NSString* buttonTitle;

- (IBAction)toggleButtonTitle:(id)sender;

@end
```

And the implementation file:

```
//  BindThisAppDelegate.m
#import "BindThisAppDelegate.h"

@interface BindThisAppDelegate()
- (void)updateButtonTitle;
@end


@implementation BindThisAppDelegate

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        m_hitCount = 0;
        [self updateButtonTitle];
    }
    return self;
}

@synthesize window = m_window;
@synthesize button = m_button;
@synthesize buttonTitle = m_buttonTitle;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self.button bind:@"title" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"buttonTitle" options:nil];
}

- (IBAction)toggleButtonTitle:(id)sender {
    m_hitCount++;
    [self updateButtonTitle];
}

- (void)updateButtonTitle {
    self.buttonTitle = (m_hitCount % 2 == 0) ? @"Even" : @"Uneven";
}

@end
```

If you store your state in an enum or integer a custom `NSValueTransformer` will help you to translate a state into its button title equivalent. You can add the `NSValueTransformer` to the binding options.

```
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[[CustomValueTransformer alloc] init] forKey:NSValueTransformerBindingOption];
[self.button bind:@"title" toObject:self withKeyPath:@"buttonTitle" options:options];
```